# Accessing model values from boot[traitName] in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have a trait, `HasLogGenerator`. The responsibility of this trait is to generate some log data whenever a predefined model event is fired. I went for this particular approach because a blanket listener/observer solution would, in my opinion, lead to way too much garbage code.

I have two models: `User` and `Store`. `User` is just a base model, but `Store` has a `belongsTo` relationship to a `StoreType`. `StoreType` contains a type-field, which resolves to a corresponding class within the project which is responsible for things like validation of a JSON-field on `StoreType`.

`LogGeneratorRepository.php` will contain all the bindings for which class name receives what generator.

```php
class LogGeneratorRepository
{
    public static array $logGenerators = [
        User::class => UserLogGenerator::class, // User is a base model
        SomeStoreType::class => OtherLogGenerator::class, // SomeStoreType is defined by a relationship on Store
        OtherStoreType::class => SomeModelLogGenerator::class, // OtherStoreType is defined by a relationship on Store
    ];

    public static function for($modelClass): Generator
    {
        if (in_array($modelClass, array_keys(self::$logGenerators))) {
            return new self::$logGenerators[$modelClass]();
        }
    }
}
```

`HasLogGenerator.php` is the trait which will bind the corresponding log generator to whatever class the trait is used on.

```php
trait HasLogGenerator
{
    public static function bootHasLogGenerator()
    {
        $generator = LogGeneratorRepository::for((self::class === Store::class)
            ? self::storeType->type // this does not work as we're in static context, and thus is the entire problem with this approach
            : self::class
        );

        // events are defined per generator
        foreach ($generator->getEvents() as $event) {
            $eventHook = "on" . ucfirst($event); // event hooks are defined as e.g. onCreated() for the generators.

            if (! method_exists($generator, $eventHook) return;

            self::{$event}(fn ($model) => $generator->{$eventHook}($model))
        }
    }
}
```

`UserLogGenerator.php` extends a base Generator class with some sensible defaults.

```php
class UserLogGenerator extends Generator
{
    // uses defaults
}
```

```php
class OtherLogGenerator extends Generator
{
    public array $events = [
        'updating', // updating instead of updated
    ];

    public function onUpdating($model)
    {
        $this->setModel($model);

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

```php
class SomeModelLogGenerator extends Generator
{
    public array $events = [
        'created', // only listens to created
    ];

    public function onCreated($model)
    {
        $this->setModel($model);

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

An example of the abstract `Generator.php`

```php
abstract class Generator
{
    public array $events = [
        'created',
        'updated',
    ];

    private array $mandatoryEvents = [
        'deleted',
    ];

    public Entity $model;

    public function getEvents()
    {
        return array_merge($this->events, $this->mandatoryEvents);
    }

    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function onCreated($model)
    {
        $this->setModel($model);

        // do stuff, like insert a row in some table, send email or whatever
    }

    public function onUpdated($model)
    {
        $this->setModel($model);

        // do stuff
    }

    public function onDeleted($model)
    {
        $this->model->logs()->delete(); // example usage
    }
}
```

So the problem revolves around resolving the class to use in `LogGeneratorRepository::for()`. I tried using the lifecycle hook `initialize[traitName]`  instead of `boot[traitName]` as that would lead to a non-static context, but found that the models are not hydrated either way.

Is there some approach I'm missing? I can't really see a way to use Laravels EventListeners and at the same time keep the code as clean.

**EDIT:**

An observer would create a mess of spaghetti ifs which would be impossible to maintain in the long run.

```php
class StoreObserver
{
    public function creating($model)
    {
        if ($model->storeType->type === SomeType::class || $model->storeType->type === SomeOtherType::class) return;

        // do work
    }

    public function created($model)
    {
        if ($model->storeType->type === SomeType::class || $model->storeType->type === SomeOtherType::class) return;

        // do work
    }

    public function updating($model)
    {
        if ($model->storeType->type === WhateverType::class || $model->storeType->type === SomeOtherType::class) return;

        if ($model->storeType->type === SpecificType::class) {
            // do specific work
        }

        // do work
    }

    public function updated($model)
    {
        if ($model->storeType->type === WhateverType::class) return;

        // do work
    }

    public function retreived($model)
    {
        if ($model->storeType->type === SomeType::class) return;

        if ($model->storeType->type === SomeOtherType::class) {
            // do specific work
        }

        if ($model->storeType->type === WhateverType::class) {
            // do specific work
        }

        // do other work
    }
}
```

Comment: What are these “log” classes doing that observers wouldn’t…?

Comment: I added an example to highlight my issue with using an observer for this.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I was going for would be great if it wasn't for the fact that my architecture is based on database structure.

I had to register a handler which did the generator switching by listening to `eloquent`-events.

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen(['eloquent.creat*', 'eloquent.updat*', 'eloquent.delet*'], function (string $eventName, array $data) {
            $event = Str::between($eventName, 'eloquent.', ':'); // events, when using wildcard matches, returns event name as "eloquent.[event]: App\\Model"

            (App::make(GeneratorRepository::class))->handle($event, Arr::first($data)); // first element is, from my experience, always the model that fired the event
        })
    }
}
```

In my GeneratorRepository I created a new method, `handle()`, which does the class resolving.

```php
class GeneratorRepository
{
    public array $generators = [
        User::class => UserGenerator::class,
        StoreTypeOne::class => StoreTypeOneGenerator::class,
        StoreTypeTwo::class => StoreTypeTwoGenerator::class,
        // etc...
    ];

    public function for(Model $model)
    {
        $type = get_class($model);

        if ($model instanceof Store) {
            $type = $model->getType(); // e.g. App\Store\Types\StoreTypeTwo, App\Store\Types\StoreTypeOne
        }

        if (in_array($type, array_keys($this->generators))) {
            return new $this->generators[$type]($model);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function handle(string $event, $model)
    {
        $generator = $this->for($model);

        if (is_null($generator)) {
            return;
        }

        if (in_array($event, $generator->getEvents()) {
            $handler = "on" . ucfirst($event);

            $generator->{$handler}($model);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach doesn't give me the freedom of just adding the trait to only the models and events I want to monitor, but it lets me access the property responsible for resolving which generator I want. This will create some overhead every time an event is fired.